# How to grep string by word in 3rd column

Tags: awk

It tried to grep strings with number <4 in 3rd column.
My data:

```
52343523412312;52343523412312;4 
52343523412312;52343523412312;4
52343523412312;52343523412312;4
52343523262412;52343523262412;3
```

I tried AWK:

```
awk -F; '$3!="4"'
```

But still receive an error - `awk: option requires an argument -- F`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Always, always, always quote every string (e.g. the `;` after `-F`) in shell unless you have a very specific reason not to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. The best way to think of using quotes when starting out is that quotes aren't something you **add** when you **think** you need to, they're something you always use by default and only **remove** when you **know** you need to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things. Your shell uses `;` as the command separator, so you need to quote it (or escape it with `\`) for your command. Also, you shouldn't quote the `4` as it's a number. Lastly, you wanted "less than 4", not "not equal to 4". So, overall, you can do:

```
awk -F';' '$3<4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    gh=i.split(';')
    if (int(gh[2]) < 4):
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
python scr.py 
52343523262412;52343523262412;3



awk ===> Alread best solution provided Below is just with if condition

 awk -F ";" '{if($3 < 4){print $0}}' filename
52343523262412;52343523262412;3
```